# URL POST parameters

Tags: url, post

I want to make a program in C# which will go/login and do stuff on a website. I'm using Fiddler to see which URL should I use.

So, in Fiddler I write:

```
https://landfill.bugzilla.org/bugzilla-tip/post_bug.cgi?Bugzilla_login=mymail@hotmail.com&Bugzilla_password=mypassword&product=WorldControl&version=1.0&component=WeatherControl&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All&priority=P2&bug_severity=normal&target_milestone=World 202.0&bug_status=CONFIRMED&assigned_to=mymail@hotmail.com&short_desc=bla
```

And I send it with POST. I get a message which says: "Are you sure you want to commit these changes anyway? This may result in unexpected and undesired results."

Then, there is a button which says 'Confirm changes'. Its code in the result html page is:

```
<form name="check" id="check" method="post" action="post_bug.cgi">
  <input type="hidden" name="product"
         value="WorldControl">
  <input type="hidden" name="version"
         value="1.0">
  <input type="hidden" name="component"
         value="WeatherControl">
  <input type="hidden" name="rep_platform"
         value="All">
  <input type="hidden" name="op_sys"
         value="All">
  <input type="hidden" name="priority"
         value="P2">
  <input type="hidden" name="bug_severity"
         value="normal">
  <input type="hidden" name="target_milestone"
         value="World 2.0">
  <input type="hidden" name="bug_status"
         value="CONFIRMED">
  <input type="hidden" name="assigned_to"
         value="mymail&#64;hotmail.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="short_desc"
         value="bla">
  <input type="hidden" name="token"
         value="aGipS2Hfim">
<input type="submit" id="confirm" value="Confirm Changes">
```

What should I write as URL in Fiddler or in browser to click this Confirm button?

Comment: You can do this by using JavaScript. For example, if you want to send first form on site, you can use forms collection forms[0].submit(). But i think this will send data that are in forms inputs.

Comment: @designerr This isn't a web application. I can't use JS.

Comment: @designerrr This isn't a web application. I can't use JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the parameters shouldn't be in the URL. This isn't GET method.

Answer (score 0):

You should submit POST data to URL https://landfill.bugzilla.org/bugzilla-tip/post_bug.cgi .

POST data should be as follows :

version=1.2&Component=WeatherControl& .... etc

Don't forget to encode POST data and set content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

*UPDATE: When you receive first answer with confirm button, parse it as DOM and submit it again to same URL.This should behave same as you click on confirm button*

Comment: I'm submiting POST data by the URL I wrote in my question. The problem is, the result I get has a button 'Confirm" which I need to press. What should be my URL